# Convert python from arcpy.da.SearchCursor to work in 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I am using code such as

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyFC, ["SHAPE@"], spatial_reference=SR):

# create inner buffer
polyBuff = row[0].buffer(buffNum * -1)

# create hull rectangle to establish a rotated area of interest
coordSplit = row[0].hullRectangle.split(' ')

# collect corner coordinates
coordList = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(coordSplit[0],coordSplit[1]),arcpy.Point(coordSplit[2],coordSplit[3]),arcpy.Point(coordSplit[4],coordSplit[5]),arcpy.Point(coordSplit[6],coordSplit[7]),arcpy.Point(coordSplit[0],coordSplit[1])])

# create lines from hull rectangle
currentLines = []
for pointNum in range(0,4):
    arcpy.Array([coordList.getObject(pointNum),coordList.getObject(pointNum+1)])
    hullRecLine = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([coordList.getObject(pointNum),coordList.getObject(pointNum+1)]))
    currentLines.append(hullRecLine)

# compare first and second line to determine if first line is short or long
firstLong = 0    
if currentLines[0].length < currentLines[1].length:
    if shortboolean == 'true':
        firstLong = 0
    else:
        firstLong = 1
if currentLines[0].length > currentLines[1].length:
    if shortboolean == 'true':
        firstLong = 1
    else:
        firstLong = 0

# calculate number of points needed along short axis
numPoints = int(math.floor(currentLines[firstLong].length/lineSpaceNum))

# create and join points to create parallel lines

for point in range(0,numPoints+1):
    shortPoint1 = currentLines[firstLong].positionAlongLine(lineSpaceNum*point)
    shortPoint2 = currentLines[firstLong + 2].positionAlongLine(currentLines[firstLong + 2].length - (lineSpaceNum*point))
    parallel = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([shortPoint1.centroid,shortPoint2.centroid]), SR)

    # intersect parallel lines with buffer
    parallelBuff = parallel.intersect(polyBuff,2)
    parallels.append(parallelBuff)
```

but this only works in ArcGIS 10.1 and newer. Is there a way to do the same thing but have it function in ArcGIS 10.0?

Comment: I think the answer to this will depend on whether you use SHAPE@ within your cursor. I suggest focussing this question down to SearchCursor and providing more of a code snippet to show what you do within it. The answer is then likely to inform you on what you need to do with Update and Insert cursors.

Comment: It is dirty looking but I am combining 3 tools into 1 - http://pastebin.com/UHQsrPGw

Comment: For focussed Q&A, and to keep the learnings on the site, I prefer to only look at code snippets when they are included within a question.

Comment: Sorry for that. I included the main line that is causing compatibility issues

Comment: I think it is now too broad - once you know the equivalent for how to do the first (or most difficult) geometry operation using a 10.0 cursor the subsequent ones should become simple - so I would reduce the code snippet to that.

Comment: The problem is Shape@ isnt in 10.0

Comment: @Beck has already provided an answer that starts to explain how old style cursors worked with geometry operations but I thought you were wanting more details to backport a specific geometry operation.

Comment: @PolyGeo I have to look at my code but I think I only use Shape@... I learned python in 10.2 so I wasnt aware that it was different in 10.0 until recently.

Comment: SHAPE@ is the arcpy.da way of getting at geometries, before that I think it was the way @Beck has described but I did little with geometries prior to 10.1 so I would need to test before answering, and before testing I like to have a focussed question to design an appropriate test for.

Answer (score 3):

use the equivelant cursor without .da.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000039000000

ex:

```
shapefieldname = arcpy.Describe(featureclass).ShapeFieldName

sCur = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureclass, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {fields}, {sort_fields})

for row in sCur:
    feature =  row.getValue(shapefieldname)
    (do stuff)
```

Comment: How would that work in something like

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polyFC, ["SHAPE@"], spatial_reference=SR):